# Declaring arrays with user input elements

Tags: c, arrays

In C, when I declare an array of `n` elements `a[n]`, and `n` is input by the user, it shouldn't work, because the array space will change from static memory to dynamic memory.

But it works! Why ?

Has the standard been updated or something?

Comment: Which compiler and what flags are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C99 standard allows for variable-length arrays, which is exactly the behaviour that your are describing.

Edit: C99 is not universally supported (at least by default). However, many compilers (such as GCC) have incorporated a subset of the C99 standard into their default compilation settings.

If you want to *disable* these features, you can do so in GCC by setting `-ansi -pedantic` in your compilation settings. This ensures that anything not supported in ANSI C will generate errors.

Comment: I'm not sure that they follow it by default.  At least, GCC requires `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` to allow some C99 features (it allows VLAs through without the option, but not `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`, for example).

Comment: To reinforce @JonathanLeffler point, Visual Studio until recently did not support C99 and still does not support VLA AFAIK.

Comment: Already corrected my answer to reflect this; However, if Visual Studio does not support VLA, then you cannot say that it supports C99!

Comment: VLA support is mandatory in C99 but optional in C11 (grrrrrr!).  Getting an accurate but nuanced answer can be hard work.  Your basic point is correct, though.

Answer (score 1):

> But it works! Why ?

Because C99 introduced [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). and you can declare dynamic arrays.

#### 6.7.6.2 Array declarators:

> If the size is an integer constant expression
> and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length
> array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.

Answer (score 1):

[Variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)(*VLA*) are a *C99* feature, so the compiler you are using supports VLA or is supporting it outside of *C99* mode as an extension, such as [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla).

the *C++* standard on the other hand does not support VLAs but many compilers including the ones I listed above support VLA in C++ as an extension.

We can see they were added in *C99* by going to the draft C99 standard in the `Foreword` section it says:

> [...]Major changes from the previous edition include:

and includes the following bullet:

> — variable length arrays